# How to sort list of objects using comparable in Dart?

Tags: sorting, dart, comparator, comparable

I want to sort a list of Items using Comparable. Item class has the following structure. I want to sort by Item's `rating` first and if there is a tie, then on the basis of `reviewQty`. This is the code I have tried so far which is not working. I also tried a Comparator but don't know how to sort with that in case of ties.

```
class MenuItem extends BaseModel implements Comparable<MenuItem>{
   final double rating;
   final int reviewQty;

   @override
   int compareTo(MenuItem other) {
   double diff = (rating - other.rating);
   return diff != 0 ? diff : this.reviewQty.compareTo(other.reviewQty);}}}
```

Tested using

```
items.sort();

items.forEach((MenuItem item) {
  print('${item.name} , ${item.rating}');
});
```

Comment: I tested your code in a dartpad and it sorts well and by reviewQty when there's a tie. What results are you getting?

Comment: The app is not loading and taking a long time even though the list has barely 12 items. I also tried using a Comparator function which works well but I don't know how to use it in case of ties?

`Comparator<MenuItem> priceComparator =
        (b, a) => a.rating.compareTo(b.rating);

    _allItems.sort(priceComparator);`

Comment: Try profiling and seeing where it bottlenecks. That is out of scope for this question though as it sorts just fine.